# How to prove this sequence is decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

My problem is how to prove 
$$\frac{1+2}{1}  > \frac{1+3+\frac{3^2}{2!}}{1+2} > \frac{1+4+\frac{4^2}{2!}+\frac{4^3}{3!}}{1+3+\frac{3^2}{2!}}>\cdots $$

I tried a lot, but fails to prove it.

Please help me...!

Comment: What exactly is the pattern?

Comment: The numerator is the first $n+1$ terms of $e^{n+1}$ and the denominator is the first $n$ terms of $e^{n}$. (Terms of the power series.) @kingW3

Comment: @kingW3: $s_n/s_{n-1}$, where $s_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^k}{k!}$, perhaps?

Comment: may be it converges to exp(1). since (1+(N+1)+(N+1)^2/2!+...+(N+1)^N/N!)/(1+N+N^2/2!+...+N^(N-1)/(N-1)!)> (1+(N+1)+(N+1)^2/2!+...|(N+1)^N/N!)/(1+N+N^2/2!+...+N^(N-1)/(N-1)!+(N+1))^N/N!)~exp(N+1)/exp(N)=exp(1). However I don't know why it is decreasing

Comment: Numerator tends to $e^{n+1}$ and denominator to $e^n$ quotient tends to $e$

Comment: Have you try doing the dirty work? Namely let $a(n)=1+n+n^2/2+\ldots+n^{(n-1)}/(n-1)!$, for $n\geq 1$. We want to show that, for every $n\geq 2$, $a(n)^2>a(n-1)a(n+1)$. Fix an arbitrary $n\geq 2$, expand $A(n)=a(n)^2-a(n-1)a(n+1)$ and see if you can show that $A(n)>0$?

Comment: So in general we need, for all $n >2$,
$$
\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^k}{k!}}{\sum_{m=0}^{n-2} \frac{(n-1)^m}{m!}} > \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(n+1)^k}{k!}}{\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^m}{m!}} 
$$
or, clearing denominators,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^k}{k!} \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^m}{m!} > \sum_{m=0}^{n-2} \frac{(n-1)^m}{m!} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(n+1)^k}{k!}
$$